# Jquery Events firing multiple times

Tags: jquery

> Firing click event multiplt times. I am having three div which all are having same class but different id's. when i click on first "a" link of first div it will fire event for three times and when i click on first "a" link of second div it will fire event for two times and when i click on first "a" link of last div it will fire event for one times.
>
> This is my html code:

```
<div class="b3">
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class = "b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_1" href="#0">
            <img src="a1.png">
                <span>
                    A1
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_2" href="#0">
            <img src="a2.png">
                <span>
                    A2
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_3" href="#0">
            <img src="a3.png">
            <span>
                A3
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_4" href="#0">
            <img src="a4.png">
            <span>
                A4
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_5" href="#0">
            <img src="a5.png">
            <span>
                A5
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="b3">
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class = "b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_11" href="#0">
            <img src="a1.png">
                <span>
                    A1
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_21" href="#0">
            <img src="a2.png">
                <span>
                    A2
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_31" href="#0">
            <img src="a3.png">
            <span>
                A3
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_41" href="#0">
            <img src="a4.png">
            <span>
                A4
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_51" href="#0">
            <img src="a5.png">
            <span>
                A5
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="b3">
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class = "b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_12" href="#0">
            <img src="a1.png">
                <span>
                    A1
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_22" href="#0">
            <img src="a2.png">
                <span>
                    A2
                </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_32" href="#0">
            <img src="a3.png">
            <span>
                A3
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_42" href="#0">
            <img src="a4.png">
            <span>
                A4
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b3_inside">
        <a class="product_a" id="a_52" href="#0">
            <img src="a5.png">
            <span>
                A5
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> This is my jquery function:

```
function gettingClick() {
$(".product_a").on("click",function(){
    var btnId = this.id;
    var str = btnId.split("_");
    if(btnId == "a_"+strt[1]){
        callMethod();
    }
});}
```

Comment: your 3 main div have the same id. Try changing them.And your are calling fun gettingClick() ?

Comment: If possible, could you please create JSFiddle or something like this?

Comment: Atula : it was by mistake written there is no id for main div

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code for trigerring an event at the click on the first link:

```
function gettingClick() {
$("#a_1").on("click",function(){
var btnId = this.id;
var str = btnId.split("_");
if(btnId == "a_"+strt[1]){
    callMethod();
}
});}
```

You need to use a "#" in the selector part to trigger click event on the first link.

Comment: All Div are created dynamically so id is not known in advance what we know in advance is about the class and part of id before "_".

Comment: If you do not know the ID of the element, you would not be able to trigger a click event on that element.
If you are creating the DIVs dynamically, also assign them proper IDs while generating them.

You can also search for the 1st or 2nd anchor tag in a div using the below function: `$(this).parents('.b3_inside').find('a:first');`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below js fiddle link its calling only once.

https://jsfiddle.net/y3uj5f6z/

```
$(".product_a").on("click",function(){
    var btnId = this.id;
    var str = btnId.split("_");
     console.log(btnId);
    if(btnId == "a_"+str[1]){
        alert(btnId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problem got solved here is the way how you can avoid overcome this triggering problem.

```
$(document).off('click','.classname').on('click','.classname',function(e){/*code*/});
```

> Thank you helping me out and your support.